# Is it possible to solve this system of equations?

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

Consider a system of equations given below:

$ p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + p_4 + p_5 = 1 $

$ x_1*p_1 + x_2*p_2 + x_3*p_3 +x_4*p_4 =0$

$ x_1^2*p_1 + x_2^2*p_2 + x_3^2*p_3 +x_4^2*p_4 =1$

$ x_1^3*p_1 + x_2^3*p_2 + x_3^3*p_3 +x_4^3*p_4 =v_1$

$ x_1^4*p_1 + x_2^4*p_2 + x_3^4*p_3 +x_4^4*p_4 =v_2$

$ x_1^5*p_1 + x_2^5*p_2 + x_3^5*p_3 +x_4^5*p_4 =v_3$

$ x_1^6*p_1 + x_2^6*p_2 + x_3^6*p_3 +x_4^6*p_4 =v_4$

$ x_1^7*p_1 + x_2^7*p_2 + x_3^7*p_3 +x_4^7*p_4 =v_5$

$ x_1^8*p_1 + x_2^8*p_2 + x_3^8*p_3 +x_4^8*p_4 =v_6$

Is there a method to solve $x_i$ and $p_i$ in terms of $v_i$?

Thank You!

Comment: You have nine equations and nine unknown variables. In principle there is a discrete amount of solutions. But I think there is no concrete algorithm to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

[A nxn nonhomogeneous system of linear equations has a unique non-trivial solution if and only if its determinant is non-zero. If this determinant is zero, then the system has either no nontrivial solutions or an infinite number of solutions.](http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/system/system.html)

Use matrices to represent this system of equations. Get the determinant of the coefficient matrix.